# Removing duplicates from large sheet

Tags: excel

I want to remove rows based on duplicate cells in a column from large sheet, without leaving duplicate sample (like "Remove Duplicates" Excel command does). So if I have:

```
1
2
2
3
```

I want, as a result:

```
1
3
```

This can be accomplished with conditional formatting, then filtering or sorting duplicates and deleting filtered data, but the process is very slow for large sheet.
Conditional formatting takes second, but just clicking on filter takes around 5min to display filter context menu and additional 20-30min to do actual filtering based on color. I tried this process on a different PCs with 4 cores and plenty of RAM and 100.000 rows sheet

I then thought to write VBA, iterate column cells and if cell is colored, then delete entire row (this is possible in Excel 2010, with `Cells().DisplayFormat`) but processing takes even more time.

Can someone suggest a faster way to remove duplicates on large sheet?

Comment: Will it be OK to have the contents of the cells (having only 1 instance) stored in dictionary and then delete the contents of the entire range & overwrite it with the unique elements?

Comment: Do you mean to iterate each cell and store cell values as dictionary keys, and row address as values, then use `If dict.exists()` to filter duplicates and delete existing occurrence if key exists?

Comment: Yes. However, no need to store the address as value in the dictionary. for e.g. the dictionary can have an aggregated view for(key=1 value=1, key=2 value=2, key=3 value=1) - where value = count of the key.

Comment: @theta: I have posted an answer below. Let me know if it helps any.

Comment: @theta: I dont believe that a simple answer has 50 points added by you. I am glad it helped you. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: Note that I have used 2 functions. Of this, `test` is a function to test whether the function works (which you will have to modify per your scenario).

Also, I filled cell A1 to A100000 with test values. Please modify it per your needs.

```
Option Explicit

Function GetUniqueItems(ByVal src As Range) As Variant
Dim returnValue

Dim dictOfItemsWith1Value
Dim dictOfItemsWithMoreThan1Value

Dim countOfCells As Long
Dim counter As Long

Dim srcValues As Variant
Dim currentValue
Dim cell As Range

srcValues = src.Value
countOfCells = src.Cells.Count

Set dictOfItemsWith1Value = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Set dictOfItemsWithMoreThan1Value = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

For counter = 1 To countOfCells
    currentValue = srcValues(counter, 1)
    If dictOfItemsWithMoreThan1Value.exists(currentValue) Then
        dictOfItemsWithMoreThan1Value(currentValue) = dictOfItemsWithMoreThan1Value(currentValue) + 1
    Else
        If Not dictOfItemsWith1Value.exists(currentValue) Then
            dictOfItemsWith1Value.Add currentValue, 1
        Else
            dictOfItemsWith1Value.Remove currentValue
            dictOfItemsWithMoreThan1Value.Add currentValue, 1
        End If
    End If
Next

ReDim returnValue(1 To dictOfItemsWith1Value.Count, 1 To 1)
Dim key

counter = 1
For Each key In dictOfItemsWith1Value.keys
    returnValue(counter, 1) = key
    counter = counter + 1
Next

GetUniqueItems = returnValue
End Function
Sub test()
Debug.Print Now
Dim uniqueValues
uniqueValues = GetUniqueItems(Range("A1:A100000"))

Range("A1:A100000").ClearContents
Range("A1").Resize(UBound(uniqueValues, 1)) = uniqueValues

Debug.Print Now
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for fast food, I didn't expect this :) Your function works beautifully and takes single second. I won't forget to add bounty two days from now for your answer. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

My way to deal with large excel files where I have to remove large chunks of data:

1. After the last column, use a `countif()` (much like KazJaw and DanM's countif)

   ```
   =COUNTIF($A$1:$A$100000,A1)
   ```

   `$A$1:$A$100000` contains your ids. Change accordingly.
2. Drag the formula to the bottom (Fill Down, or select the range `$B$1:$B$100000` if this is the column you put the helper column then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>)
3. Copy column and paste values in place to remove the formula. This will prevent any recalculations during/after any filtering.
4. Sort by the column with the counts. This makes deleting the large portion of rows much faster later on.
5. Look for where you start to get counts of 2 and delete all rows till bottom.
6. Delete the helper column.

Now, if you want to restore the original order, put yet another column after the count, after step 3 above, and after step 5, sort this new column by ascending order before deleting it in step 6.

Comment: Steps 2 and 4 should be the most time consuming while the other steps should be relatively quick, with step 3 somewhat fast.

Comment: @pnuts I actually prefer: 'Click cell', 'scroll to bottom', 'hold Shift and click last cell', 'hit Ctrl+D' :) Works if there are blank cells in adjacent column.

Answer (score 1):

If you data is in located in column A, this formula should do what you need fairly efficiently:

```
=COUNTIF(A$1:A$100000,A1)
```

This formula counts how many times the value in A1 appears in the range A1:A100000. (The dollar signs keep that range from moving down as your drag your formula down.)

Place this in B1 and drag down* to B100000 (assuming you have 100,000 rows).

Then just do a filter on column B to show only 1. (More than 1 means you have duplicates and shouldn't show it.)

*A short cut for dragging down is to just select B1, then press Ctrl-End, then hold down shift and click B100000. Then do Ctrl-D (which is a shortcut for Fill Down).

Comment: This is indeed faster, thanks. I actually tried this function earlier and as the result wasn't instant I hesitated to fill whole column as I thought it would take forever, and went to VBA.